# jQuery tabs plugin with callback to fetch data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I want to use [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) plugin and load tab contents using `ajax`. The problem is: the plugin requires a solid `.php` file to be specified in `href` e.g.

```
<li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
```

You know this does not work well with WordPress. A callback here would have worked. Is there such fork available Or any other plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the proper WordPress Ajax API (well not really an api)
for example:

```
<li><a href="url to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_ajax_tabs&tab=tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="url to wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_ajax_tabs&tab=tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
```

then you create a function that will respond to the ajax calls:

```
function do_my_tabs(){
    $tab = $_GET['tab'];
    switch ($tab){
    case "tab1":
        echo 'tab1 content';
        break;
    case "tab2":
        echo 'tab2 content';
        break;
    }
    die();
}
```

and last just hook this function :

```
//if you want only logged in users to access this function use this hook
add_action('wp_ajax_my_ajax_tabs', 'do_my_tabs');

//if you want none logged in users to access this function use this hook
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_tabs', 'do_my_tabs');

//if you want both logged in users and guests to access this function then add both
```